# Submit button to post data via ajax made from createhtml not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

What do I have to do to make second button works? the first button runs smoothly, but the second not, if you click test_link it will show the second button, which is created by javascript

```
<script src="http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/assets/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $(".comment_button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType : "json",
                url: "http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/index.php/talk/test",
                data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
                success : function(cont) {
                    if(cont){
                        $.each(cont, function(key, val) {
                            alert(key+" "+val);
                        });
                        }
                     }              
            }); 
            return false;               
        });

        $(".comment_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("post_id");
        $("#"+id).html('<input><button class="comment_button">Second button, not work</button>');  
        return false;
        });         
    });
    </script>



        <form method="post" action="http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/index.php/talk/test/2">
        <button class="comment_button">first button, this_button works</button>
        </form>
        <div id="7"></div>
        <a href="http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/index.php/talk/test/2" class="comment_link" post_id="7">test_link</a>
        <br>
        php code : <?php echo json_encode($_POST);?>
```

Comment: Take a look into `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/ It should be what you're looking for.  Since your click is ready before the HTML is actually made, the old click that you are using does not even know that the element exists.  .on() kind of refreshes the elements to look for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `.click()` method before the button is added to the DOM, you could redefine your JavaScript like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".comment_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("post_id");
        $("#" + id).html('<input><button class="comment_button">Second button, not work</button>')
        .children(".comment_button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/index.php/talk/test",
                data: {
                    name: "John",
                    time: "2pm"
                },
                success: function (cont) {
                    if (cont) {
                        $.each(cont, function (key, val) {
                            alert(key + " " + val);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Chaining the method `.click()` after adding the button, and looking it up on the parent. 
Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".comment_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("post_id");
        $("#" + id).html('<input><button class="comment_button">Second button, not work</button>')
            .children(".comment_button").click(commentButtonClicked);
        return false;
    });

    function commentButtonClicked() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost/googledrive/www/ci/2.1.3/social/index.php/talk/test",
            data: {
                name: "John",
                time: "2pm"
            },
            success: function (cont) {
                if (cont) {
                    $.each(cont, function (key, val) {
                        alert(key + " " + val);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Moving your ajax call to a separate non-anonymous function and calling it from the `.click()` event chained like in the previous example...